# Different behaviour of static_cast

Tags: c++, json, casting

I am trying to convert a uint64_t to a uint8_t. I know this makes no sense normaly but since the [JSON Library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) converts all numeric values to a uint64_t or int64_t I have to convert it back. I am always sure I do not receive values which will not fit into the uint8_t.

Now when I compile and run the following code on OSx everything works as expected. But as soon as I move to a Raspberry Pi 2 the code no longer works. The value is 0.

Can anybody explain why this is happening? And does somebody has a better solution?

```
#include <iostream>

#include "json.h"

using JSON = nlohmann::json;

typedef struct {
    uint8_t boardId;
    uint8_t commandGroupId;
    uint8_t commandId;
} ExternalMessageType;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    JSON x;
    ExternalMessageType y;

    x["board-id"] = 1;
    x["command-group-id"] = 1;
    x["command-id"] = 11;

    y.boardId = static_cast<uint8_t>(x["board-id"]);
    y.commandGroupId = static_cast<uint8_t>(x["command-group-id"]);
    y.commandId = static_cast<uint8_t>(x["command-id"]);

    std::cout << "Board: " << (int)y.boardId << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Group: " << (int)y.commandGroupId << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Command: " << (int)y.commandId << std::endl;

    if (y.commandGroupId == 1) {
        std::cout << "Command Group is ok." << std::endl;
        switch (y.commandId) {
            case 11: {
                std::cout << "Speed Message" << std::endl;
            } break;
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Command Group is not ok." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try `(int)number` in the cout line

Comment: There are no warnings, the version is "The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0"

Comment: `x["a"]` will insert a null element if it doesn't exist, maybe check that. Also, check if `static_cast` is appropriate for converting whatever JSON type that returns - maybe you have to use `x["a"].asint()` or something.

Comment: @Pascal put the relevant information into the question, not comments.

Comment: You are aware of that it will not display the number `8` anyway? The type `uint8_t` is likely an alias for `unsigned char` and the only operator overloads for `<<` that takes a `char` (signed or unsigned) is to output it as a *character* not a number.

Comment: yes when I change the output to (int)number it shows up on the console. But my problem persists because now I have to put a (int) infront of every use of my number variable. So if I want to compare `if(number == 1)` then this does not work but when i write `if((int)number == 1)` then it works.

Comment: Pascal, are you sure about needing a cast for the comparison? It should work without cast -- try it first (the compiler converts the value implicitly to int before comparing as part of the usual arithmetic conversions!). The reason you need it for output is likely what Joachim said (although the char with ASCII code 8 is a backspace and should not print a 0 glyph; that's a bit puzzling).

Comment: I will write a better example code and check it again.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: "The compiler converts the value implicitly to int before comparing". I would say the reverse: the console convert the int value to a nice character picture when required by cout.